# Parsing nested elements in an XML file using Java

Tags: java, xml

Currently, this is what my XML file looks like. There's 10 more students, but I figured you didn't need to see that.

```
<Student id="11111">
    <FirstName>Joe</FirstName>
    <LastName>Edwards</LastName>
    <Address>
        <Street>345 North</Street>
        <City>Brea</City>
        <State>CA</State>
        <Zip>99999</Zip>
        <Phone>(714) 444-4444</Phone>
    </Address>
    <Classes>
        <Class crn="5555">
            <Name>CIS 100</Name>
            <Units>3</Units>
            <Grade>A</Grade>
        </Class>
        <Class crn="7777">
            <Name>CIS 111</Name>
            <Units>4</Units>
            <Grade>B</Grade>        
        </Class>
    </Classes>
</Student>
```

And this is my code to 'extract' the first and last names, respectively.

```
NodeList studentlist = doc.getElementsByTagName("Student");

        for(int i = 0; i < studentlist.getLength(); i++)
        {
            Node n = studentlist.item(i); 
            Element element = (Element)n; 
            String id = element.getAttribute("id");
            Student obj = new Student(id);
            NodeList slist = n.getChildNodes();

            for (int j = 0; j < slist.getLength(); j++)
            {
                Node selement = slist.item(j);

                if (selement.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                {
                    String textval = selement.getTextContent();

                    if (selement.getNodeName().equals("FirstName"))
                    {
                        obj.setFirstname(textval);
                    }
                    if (selement.getNodeName().equals("LastName"))
                    {
                        obj.setLastname(textval);
                    }
                }
            }

            students.add(obj);
        }
```

And my Student class:

```
public class Student 
{
    private String id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private Address adr;
    private ArrayList<Course> courses;
```

My question is this: how do I add the 'address' and 'classes' nodes for this same object?

Comment: A question about parsing XML that doesn't use regex. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, one way to approach this is to create Data structures for both Address and Class, like so:

```
public class Address
{
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zip;
    private String phone;
}
```

and (note: calling a Java Class "Class" may prove to be very confusing, so use something else I'd say)

```
public class Course
{
    private int crn;
    private String name;
    private String units;
    private String grade;
}
```

(and you'll have to create constructors for both of those classes too)

Then, in your for-loop, in the outer "if" block, after the "if" statements that check the node names for "FirstName" and "LastName", you could do something like:

```
if (selement.getNodeName().equals("Address"))
{
    String street = null;
    String city = null;
    String state = null;
    String zip = null;
    String phone = null;
    NodeList addressChildren = selement.getChildNodes();
    for(int k=0; k < addressChildren.getLength(); k++) {
        Node addrNode = addressChildren.item(k);
        if(addrNode.getNodeName().equals("Street")
        {
           street = addrNode.getTextContent();
        }
        ...//etc for City, State, Zip, and Phone
        Address a = new Address(street, city, state, zip, phone)
        obj.setAddress(a);
    }
}
if (selement.getNodeName().equals("Classes"))
{
    NodeList classNodes = selement.getChildNodes();
    Course[] courses = new Course[classNodes.getLength());
    for(int l=0; l < classNodes.getLength(); l++) {
        Node classNode = classNodes.item(l);
        NodeList classChildren = classNode.getChildNodes();
        for(int m=0; m < classChildren.getLenght(); m++)
        {
            Node classChild = classChildren.item(i);
            int crn = Integer.parseInt(classChild.getAttributes().getNamedItem("crn").getTextContent());
            String name = null;
            String units = null;
            if(classChild.getNodeName().equals("Name")
            {
               name = classChild.getTextContent();
            }
            if(classChild.getNodeName().equals("Units")
            {
               units = classChild.getTextContent();
            }
            courses[m] = new Course(crn, name, units);
        }
        obj.setCourses(Arrays.asList(courses));
    }
}
```

Ok, so the code above isn't perfect (I wrote it in the browser), but I think, based on what you've already figured out about XML parsing, that this is a good start.

Comment: Woo, thank you for your reply. I actually do have separate classes for both the Address and Course classes, I just didn't add them to the code above because I figured it was unnecessary to do so. Since this 'comment' block is tiny, I'll add what I have here: https://ideone.com/zzgObB

Comment: My question, now is this: I see that you have added the following: obj.setCourses(//etc etc etc) and obj.setAddress(a) - how do I add those to the student arraylist like I did with the first and last names? If you'll notice at the end of the 'if' statements you were referring to earlier, I have students.add(obj) - how do I do that for the rest of the information?

Comment: Also, my 'address' and 'course' classes do not have a constructor set up the way you have - they look like this, instead. Address: https://ideone.com/RGfJsD and Course: https://ideone.com/q9faOt. Should I change the constructor accordingly, or how would I modify the code to match them? Finally, what did you mean to do with this line? obj.setCourses(Arrays.asList(courses));

Comment: Update: this is currently what that method looks like: https://ideone.com/sNCOjQ/. However, line 123 is wrong and I'm not sure what to change it to.

Comment: If you are having trouble with Arrays.asList, delete the 'courses' variable, and create an ArrayList in its place (ArrayList<Course> coursesList = new ArrayList<Course>), and replace the line "courses[m] = new Course(...);" with "courseList.add(new Course(...));". Finally, obj.setCourses(courseList);     Instead of using a constructor (Address f = new Address(street, city...);), use the empty constructor (f = new Address();), and then use your setters (f.setStreet(street); etc);

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I had already changed the address section, so thank you for the help with the courses section. However, I am now getting an error whenever I go to compile: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at assignOneMain.createArray(assignOneMain.java:46)
 at assignOneMain.main(assignOneMain.java:22). Here's main: https://ideone.com/Ue9BnR. It seems there's a problem with the following line:   NodeList studentlist = doc.getElementsByTagName("Student"); and   students = createArray(doc); thoughts on this?

Comment: It looks like the variable "doc" on line 46 is likely null. Line 21 has a Document.createDocument("file.xml") call that is returning null. Put the line "return doc;" after line 181...that should fix it. Also, if you don't mind, please mark my answer as accepted (by clicking the checkmark). Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, thank you, that fixed it! Another thing - the method you helped me with just now, the createArray method - is that 'loading' the students into the array? Because I need to make a method that loads the students, and another that searches for the students. I have a pretty good idea of how to implement the latter, but I'm confused as to how I'm supposed to load the xml file to begin with. Isn't that what the createArray method is doing?

Comment: Yes, using common nomenclature, "createArray()" does, in fact, load the students into the array.